# How to use a Node.js library on client side javascript where a server is not available

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova

I'm creating an Ethereum wallet in phonegap. I need to use the Vanitheth library to generate the keypairs (https://github.com/MyEtherWallet/VanityEth)

My problem is that VanityEth runs on node.js, which require a server. Phonegap runs client-side code, so I need to somehow make this library accessible to phonegap without connecting to a server or node. Is there a way to convert this library into a .js front end file that I could include in my application and access it?

Comment: I wouldn't even use this in Node, it relies on the crypto module, which is deprecated.

Comment: It doesn't _need_ NodeJS. It'll be more straightforward to g through it. But you can still bundle this lib (and its dependencies) with some packages such as browserify or webpack to use it client side.